# Recommended 3D Programming Aspects for Light/Laser Show Simulator?

Tags: graphics, 3d, xna, lighting

Hey guys, I would like to develop a light/laser show editor and simulator, and for this of course I am going to learn some graphics programming. I am thinking about using C# and XNA.

I was just wondering what aspects of graphics programming I should research or focus on given the project I am working on. I am new to graphics programming so I don't know much about it, but for example I imagine something that I might look into would (*possibly?*) be volumetric lighting.

For example, what would be a practical way to go about rendering a 'laser' of varied width/color? I read somewhere to just draw a cylinder and apply a shader to it, I would like to confirm that this is the way.

Given that this seems like a big project, I was thinking about starting off by creating light sources and giving them properties so that I can easily manipulate them. I have (mis)read that only a certain amount of lights can be rendered at any given time, I believe eight. Does this only apply to ambient lights? Given this possible limitation, and the fact that most of the lights I will use will be directional, such as head-lights or lasers, what would be a different way to render these? Is that what volumetric lighting would be?

I'd just like to get some things clear before I dive into it. Since I'm new to this I probably didn't make the best use of words, so if something doesn't make sense please let me know. Thanks and sorry for my ignorance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this depends on the level of sophistication that you need in your display simulation. Computer graphics is ultimately a simulation of the transport of light; that simulation can be as sophisticated as calculating the fraction of laser light deflected by particles in the atmosphere to the viewer's eyepoint, or as simple as drawing a line. Try out the cylinder effect and see if it works for your project. If you need something more sophisticated, look into shader programming (using Nvidia Cg, for example), and volumetric shading as you mentioned; also post-processing glow effects may be useful. For OpenGL, I believe there is a limit of 8? light sources in a scene, but you could conceivably work around this limit by doing your own shading logic.

Comment: You can through at the latest SIGGRAPH papers for inspiration to see if there are projects related to lighting effects; some of these may also help you: http://www.cs.rit.edu/~jmg/courses/procshade/20073/papers.html

Answer (score 1):

Well if it's just for light show simulations I'd imagine your going to need a lot of custom lighting effects - so regardless if you decide to use XNA or straight DirectX your best bet would be to start by learning shader languages and how to program various lighting effects using them.  Once you can reproduce the type of laser lighting you want, then you can experiment with the polygons you want to use to represent the lasers.  (I've used the cylinder method in some of my work for personal purposes, but I'm not sure how well straight cylinders will fit your purpose).

Answer (score 0):

Although its faster, I think its best not to use vanilla hardware lighting because of its limitations. Pixel shaders can help with you task. Also you may want to chose OpenGL because of portability and its clarity in rendering methods. I worked on Direct3D for several years before switching to OpenGL. OpenGL functions and states are easier to learn and rendering methods (like multi-pass rendering) is a lot clear. If you like to code on C# (which I dont recommend for these tasks), you can use CsGL library to access OpenGL functions.